HoloLens2 can't discovery wifi direct device
I have use WiFi-Direct connect HoloLens2 with android pad succeed. But, sometime HoloLens2 can't enumerate android pad succeed, only restart HoloLens2 will discovery pad again,what's the problem?
I have try to discovery in loop, but no effect ,still can't discovery the pad, and i try the example https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/WiFiDirect can connect to pad succeed, so the problem should be the HoloLens2 side.
